# Switching from GET to POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have the following Ajax request:

```
// JavaScript
function myFunc(pid) {
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : "testback.php",
        contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType : "json",
        data : {
            q : "testrequest",
            pid : pid
        },
        success : function(data) {
            console.log(data)
        },
        error : function(jqXHR, status, error) {
            console.log(status, error);
        }
    });
}

// PHP
require_once ("dbconnect.php");
if (isset ( $_GET ['q'] )) {
    if ($_GET ['q'] == "testrequest") {
        $pid = $_GET ['pid'];

        $query = "SELECT * FROM `tab1` WHERE `pid` = " . $pid;

        $json = array ();
        if ($result = $link->query ( $query )) {
            while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc () ) {
                array_push ( $json, $row );
            }
        }

        header ( "Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8" );
        die ( json_encode ( $json ) );
        exit ();
    }
    die ();
}
```

It sends a request to my MySQL database and returns the expected output.

However, I now want to switch to `POST`, rather than `GET`.
When I just swap GET with POST:

```
// JavaScript
function myFunc(pid) {
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST", // POST
        url : "testback.php",
        contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType : "json",
        data : {
            q : "testrequest",
            pid : pid
        },
        success : function(data) {
            console.log(data)
        },
        error : function(jqXHR, status, error) {
            console.log(status, error);
        }
    });
}

// PHP
require_once ("dbconnect.php");
if (isset ( $_POST ['q'] )) { // POST
    if ($_POST ['q'] == "testrequest") { // POST
        $pid = $_POST ['pid']; // POST

        $query = "SELECT * FROM `tab1` WHERE `pid` = " . $pid;

        $json = array ();
        if ($result = $link->query ( $query )) {
            while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc () ) {
                array_push ( $json, $row );
            }
        }

        header ( "Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8" );
        die ( json_encode ( $json ) );
        exit ();
    }
    die ();
}
```

I get the following error in the console:

> parsererror SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

The request payload is still `q=testrequest&pid=1`.

What else do I need to change, in order to switch from `GET` to `POST`?

Comment: use `json_decode()` in your $_POST query

Comment: @ixe: Can you tell me, where exactly?

Comment: @user1170330 remove `contentType` and `dataType` settings

Comment: @postrel: Now, I just get an empty response. Without any errors or other data.

Comment: Use $_REQUEST if you dont know which is the method of submission, it receives both GET and POST data.  and you are getting this error because formation of JSON is not valid.

Comment: @user1170330 make a test to see what your `$_POST` contains when you submit your ajax. You could print it or call var_dump() on it. Also your SQL query is vulnerable to injections. Use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) in PDO or mysqli

Answer (score 1):

In your Ajax function you need to omit the content type as it is already defined in the Ajax Call. Delete the line "contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8" shown below:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "GET", // Or POST
    url : "testback.php",
    contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8", // REMOVE THIS LINE!!
    dataType : "json",
    data : {
        q   : "testrequest",
        pid : pid
    },
    success : function(data) {
        console.log(data)
    },
    error : function(jqXHR, status, error) {
        console.log(status, error);
    }
});
```

It should work just fine after that!
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The $.ajax works but i advise to use $.get or $.post instead.
Be carrefull about your url when you use $.get, browsers have caracter limits (around 2000 caracters).

```
if (urlGet.length < 2000) {  
  // GET less than 2000 caractères use $.GET
  $.get(urlGet, function () {

  }).done(function (data) {
    //OK do stuff with data returned
  }).fail(function () {
    //err
  });
} else {
  //Use $.POST params : { name: "John", age: "25" }
  $.post(urlPost, { name: "John", age: "25" }, function () {

  }).done(function () {
    //ok
  }).fail(function () {
    //fail
  });
}
```

You can create a function with this code and then have a simple call of your WebServices.

Here is the jQuery doucmentation :

$.GET https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

$.POST https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Hope this help ;)